# Vector sorting with lambda function, how to pass in variable to capture group when not in the same scope?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, lambda

Essentially I have quite a large lambda function for sorting a vector of custom objects. The only issue is that the lambda function is dependent on a object that is passed to it via a capture group. This has worked fine for some time, however now I want to reuse the same function in different parts of the program. Here's what my code looks like:

```
void fun(int i) {
...

BarMovement movement(i);

auto sortByBarMovement = [movement](OrderLogic::OpenOrder const& order1, OrderLogic::OpenOrder const& order2) -> bool
{
    ...
};

std::sort(std::begin(same_bar_order_fill), std::end(same_bar_order_fill), sortByBarMovement);

...
}
```

I would like to move the `sortByBarMovement` lambda into it's own function so I can reuse it. However it's dependent on the item `movement` in the capture group.

How in C++ can I pass this `movement` object to the lambda function if I move `sortByBarMovement` to a different scope?

Comment: By move do you mean `std::move` the lambda, or do you mean modify the source code to place the lambda's logic into a named function?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux lambda's logic into a named function. Thanks

Comment: Why not simply write a function instead of lambda?

Comment: Your lambda is stateful, it has an internal state (the captured `movement` object) and you can have multiple instances of `sortByBarMovement` at the same time with different states. This is not possible with functions, you need some sort of object to manage the possible states. You cannot make instances of functions, they are not object, so they cannot have associated instances of `BarMovement` except by passing them through an argument. But that would change the signature. Only stateless lambdas can be easily converted to functions.

Comment: @ALX23z I suppose this is what I had in mind. I'm unsure as to how this would work with the std::sort method though, since it uses the parameters `OrderLogic::OpenOrder const& order1, OrderLogic::OpenOrder const& order2`, since I need to pass in a third one (being `BarMovement`)

Comment: @Tom Have you considered writing a function that returns that lambda instead?

Comment: Move it into a function like sort_with_bar_movement(const BarMovement& bm, std::vector<Foo>& to_sort) and call the std::sort inside that one while giving a reference to your movement object

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I did consider it but it feels too weird to not simply call a constructor

Comment: You can put all the long logic into the function. Then simply make a very short lambda with captures that simply calls the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda is just syntactic sugar for functors. One big plus is that you can write lambdas inline, in the same scope, directly at the place where you use it. On the other hand, if you want to reuse it elsewhere, there is no big advantage of a lambda compared to a plain function object. Maybe it is more clear if you skip the sugar:

```
struct sortByBarMovement_type {
    BarMovement movement;
    sortByBarMovement_type(const BarMovement& movement) : movement(movement) {}
    bool operator()(OrderLogic::OpenOrder const& order1, OrderLogic::OpenOrder const& order2) const {
        ...
    }
};
```

And thats basically all you need. `fun` now looks like this:

```
void fun(int i) {
...

BarMovement movement(i);

sortByBarMovement_type sortByBarMovement{movement};

std::sort(std::begin(same_bar_order_fill), std::end(same_bar_order_fill), sortByBarMovement);

...
}
```

PS: I tried to be as close as possible to your code. Thats why I make a copy of `movement`. Maybe keeping a reference is sufficient. Also your lambdas `operator()` is `const` but `sortByBarMovement_type::operator()` must not necessarily be `const`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class to keep a reference to the `BarMovement` and implement `operator()` for the comparisons:

```
struct sortByBarMovement {
    sortByBarMovement(const BarMovement& bm) : bmref(bm) {}

    bool operator()(const OrderLogic::OpenOrder& order1,
                    const OrderLogic::OpenOrder& order2) const
    {
        // logic ...
        return <result>;
    }

    const BarMovement& bmref;
};

std::sort(std::begin(same_bar_order_fill),
          std::end(same_bar_order_fill), sortByBarMovement(movement));
```